# Bootstrap Navbar only showing collapsed edit: Fixed But Navbar not collapsing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, navbar

**Edit:**

I have now fixed this issue, but now the navbar will not collapse.

Does this mean my media queries are missing?

Which folder should these be in? It has been a while since I added them and I cannot find them in my less/css files

I am quite new to web-design so am having some issues with my navbar

It was displaying fine and collapsing fine, but Less wasn't compiling as there was an issue with my folders structure. When I changed the bootstrappath (@bootstrappath) I could compile my work again but my navbar broke.

Instead of showing my default navbar and collapsed navbar on small screen, my navbar shows as just one line and a drop down menu when you click on it.

I am concerned it is something to do with me changing the bootstrap path and I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried changing the @grid-float-breakpoint but with no luck.

Here is my code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default text-center">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> 
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.php">About</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/services/seo.php">Search Engine Optimisation</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/media-management.php">Social Media Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/analysis.php">Analysis</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/blog.php">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog.php">Our Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help much appreciated. All was fine until I got a new laptop and transferred the files over and since then it has gone rather wrong. I am rather new to this so please go easy on me! Thanks

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: How do I do that as I am using bootstrap?

Comment: Do I just post the html or the css/less too? Sorry I am rather new to this

Comment: ever heard of Bootstrap CDN? https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: just add the default bootstrap code and your html markup + the js or css that you've added.